# efeito de trasição em menu não funciona no chrome no firefox funciona normal

Tags: css, google-chrome, transição

Esse é o código CSS:

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;  
}
header{
margin-top:10px;


}
nav{

margin:0px auto;
max-width:1000px;
width:100%;

}
nav ul {
list-style:none;
}

nav > ul {
display:table;
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
background:#E8E8E8;
position:relative;

}

nav > ul li {
display:table-cell;

}
/* Sub-menu*/
nav > ul > li:hover > ul{
display:inline;
height:100%;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
display:block;
position:absolute;
background:#CDCDC1;
left:0;
right:0;
overflow:hidden;
height:0%;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav > ul li a {
color:#000;
display:block;
line-height:20px;
padding:20px;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
nav > ul > li > ul >li a:hover{
background:#87CEFF;
}

nav > ul > li > a span{
background:#174459;
display:block;
height:100%;
width:100%;
left:0;
position:absolute;
top:-55px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
nav > ul > li > a span .icon {
display:block;
line-height:80px;
}
nav > ul > li > a:hover > span {
top:0;
}
/* Cores*/
nav ul li a .primeiro{
background:#00BFFF;
}
nav ul li a .segundo{
background:#00BFFF;
}
nav ul li a .terceiro{
background:#00BFFF;
}
nav ul li a .quarto{
background:#00BFFF;
}
nav ul li a .quinto{
background:#00BFFF;
}
nav ul li a .sexto{
background:#00BFFF;
}
```

Esse é o HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link href="css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo_menu5.css">  
</head>
<body>  
<div> 
   <header>
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="primeiro"><i class="icon"><img src="img/House.png" width="30" height="30"/></i></span>Escola</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Cadastro</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Coordenação Pedagógica</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">LSE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Relatórios</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Usuários</a></li>
               </ul>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#"><span class="segundo"><i class="icon"><img src="img/Schoolbag.png" width="30" height="30" /></i></span></i>Aluno</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Pesquisar Aluno</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Relatórios</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="terceiro"><i class="icon"><img src="img/People.png" width="30" height="30"/></i></span>Turmas</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Cadastrar Turma</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Listar Turma</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="quarto"><i class="icon"><img src="img/Arithmetic.png" width="30" height="30" /></i></span>Professor</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Carga Horária</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Enturmar Professor</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="penn.html"><span class="quinto"><i class="icon"><img src="img/Delete.png" width="30" height="30" /></i></span>Pendência</a></li>
            <li><a href="DOWNN.html#"><span class="sexto"><i class="icon"><img src="img/Down.png" width="30" height="30" /></i></span>Download</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: dvd sua solução foi brilhante porém quando executo o código aqui pela pagina stackOVERFLOW kkk olha a ironia meu problema é o overflow...bem funciona corretamente quando faço as mudanças na minha página a faixa branca não SOBREPÕE das figuras. :(

Comment: ajustei a altura e top e funcionou...obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no `overflow:hidden;` em `nav > ul`. O Chrome, diferentemente dos outros navegadores, interpreta isso de forma diferente.

Quando você seta `overflow` no elemento, o Chrome delimita todos os elementos-filhos a área do elemento-pai. O que ultrapassar os limites, não serão exibidos. A sua transição está funcionando corretamente, mas não aparece porque fica fora dos limites do elemento-pai.

A única forma que encontrei de solucionar isso de forma visual foi criando uma nova `div` com fundo branco e de altura de `10px` que irá sobrepor e para esconder parte das `<li>` que descem do topo. E, claro, deletando a linha `overflow` do `nav > ul`.

Criei uma `div` e dei `id` de `faixa` logo após a abertura da `div` principal:

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;  
}
header{
margin-top:10px;
}
nav{

margin:0px auto;
max-width:1000px;
width:100%;

}
nav ul {
list-style:none;
}

nav > ul {
display:table;
width:100%;
background:#E8E8E8;
position:relative;

}

nav > ul li {
display:table-cell;

}
/* Sub-menu*/
nav > ul > li:hover > ul{
display:inline;
height:100%;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
display:block;
position:absolute;
background:#CDCDC1;
left:0;
right:0;
overflow:hidden;
height:0%;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;
}

nav > ul li a {
color:#000;
display:block;
line-height:20px;
padding:20px;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
nav > ul > li > ul >li a:hover{
background:#87CEFF;
}

nav > ul > li > a span{
background:#174459;
display:block;
height:100%;
width:100%;
left:0;
position:absolute;
top:-55px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
-moz-transition: all .3s ease;
transition: all .3s ease;
}
nav > ul > li > a span .icon {
display:block;
line-height:80px;
}
nav > ul > li > a:hover > span {
top:0;
}
/* Cores*/
nav ul li a .primeiro{
background:#00BFFF;
}
nav ul li a .segundo{
background:#00BFFF;
}
nav ul li a .terceiro{
background:#00BFFF;
}
nav ul li a .quarto{
background:#00BFFF;
}
nav ul li a .quinto{
background:#00BFFF;
}
nav ul li a .sexto{
background:#00BFFF;
}

#faixa{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   background: #fff;
   height: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div id="faixa"></div>
   <header>
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="primeiro"><i class="icon"><img src="img/House.png" width="30" height="30"/></i></span>Escola</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Cadastro</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Coordenação Pedagógica</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">LSE</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Relatórios</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Usuários</a></li>
               </ul>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#"><span class="segundo"><i class="icon"><img src="img/Schoolbag.png" width="30" height="30" /></i></span></i>Aluno</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Pesquisar Aluno</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Relatórios</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="terceiro"><i class="icon"><img src="img/People.png" width="30" height="30"/></i></span>Turmas</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Cadastrar Turma</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Listar Turma</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="quarto"><i class="icon"><img src="img/Arithmetic.png" width="30" height="30" /></i></span>Professor</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Carga Horária</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Enturmar Professor</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="penn.html"><span class="quinto"><i class="icon"><img src="img/Delete.png" width="30" height="30" /></i></span>Pendência</a></li>
            <li><a href="DOWNN.html#"><span class="sexto"><i class="icon"><img src="img/Down.png" width="30" height="30" /></i></span>Download</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @fabrito Tenta aumentando o valor do z-index. Em vez de 9, coloca 99999999 (vários noves).